# Protractor Match Text

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, protractor

How would I write a protractor function that will search the page for a string of text and return a state of whether or not that string of text is present on the page, visible, hidden, etc.

The idea is to fulfill the step definitions for "I shall see" such that I can say "I shall see" for all visible elements, and "I should not see" for hidden elements"

Comment: Your question is slightly vague - can you post a simplified sample of the HTML you're testing, and what exactly you're trying to assert? Also, there generally should not be a need to search through the entire page for text if you can write a more targeted selector. However, if you must go that route, you can search for all elements on the page that contain the string "woohoo" (as an example) using the following locator: `element.all(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(),'woohoo')]'))`

Comment: What would this return? Does the xpath give us back the div where the text was found or a true/false?

Comment: That would return a div where that text was found. Or to be more exact, that would return a promise that resolves to an array of all elements (regardless of type) containing that text. Example of how to use element.all here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementall