# how to click link in a table based on the text in a row protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, protractor

### Angular JS - Protractor

How can i click on the Options menu based on the span text 'BG558' in a table of rows. There are lot of rows. Please some body help me using Protractor

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-style="styleForDownLineActivities)" ng-class="ficGridAlert" bn-log-dom-creation="With" ng-repeat="baseLocationAndActivities in LocationAndActivities | baseLocationFilter:searchCriteria track by baseLocationAndActivities.baseNumber">
<td class="ng-binding" style="width : 30px"></td>
<td class="ng-binding" style="width : 30px">24</td>
<td style="width : 49px">
    <tlr-station-c>
        <span class="ng-binding ficSmartMenu" fic:circ7="baseLocationAndActivities.systemC" ng-class="ficSmartMenu" ng-show="editCriteria">BG558</span>  <!-- Based on this text -->
        <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="editCriteria">
    </tlr-station-c>
</td>
<td style="width : 102px">
    <td class="ng-binding" style="width : 30px">UT</td>
    <td style="width : 30px">
        <td style="width : 30px">
            <td style="width : 25px">
                <td style="width : 25px">
                    <td style="width : 25px">
                        <td style="width : 25px">
                            <td style="width : 25px">
                                <td style="width : 25px">
                                    <td style="width : 25px">
                                        <td style="width : 75px">
                                            <td style="width : 75px">
                                                <td style="width : 75px">
                                                    <td align="center" style="width : 65px">
                                                        <span class="ficSmartMenu ng-scope" ng-if="(!baseEditableMode && !baseCEditMode && FSNNum < 0)">
                                                            Options <!-- I should able to click this element -->
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to include an id of the link in the markup?

Comment: Hey there is no id for Options(it is not a link) it's a smartmenu

Comment: from [Protractor Match Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791225/protractor-match-text) element.all(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(),'woohoo')]'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I used xpath for that

```
element(by.xpath("//span[contains(.,'BG558')]/following::span[contains(.,'Options')][1]").click();
```